# loop in node via command line windows

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node and I want to loop trough commands in the command line using node. the commands look like:

```
node dist/main.js dist/index.html dynamic /
node dist/main.js dist/index.html dynamic page.html
node dist/main.js dist/index.html dynamic page2.html
```

I am using angular4 universal and to rerender my pages I have to put these commands in the command prompt. It wouldn't be a problem if I didn't have like 20 pages already and still more to come. My hand gets sore hehe..

How do I do this?

Thanks in regards!

the main.js file

```
 import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from './src/app.server.module.ngfactory'
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
enableProdMode();
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
if (args.length != 3) {
    process.stdout.write("Usage: node dist/main.js <document> <distDir> <url>\n");
    process.exit();
}
const indexFileContent = fs.readFileSync(args[0], 'utf8');
renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    document: indexFileContent,
    url: args[2]
}).then(string => {
    let destUrl = args[2];
    if (destUrl == '/')
        destUrl = 'index.html'
    const targetDir = args[1] + '/' + destUrl;
    targetDir.split('/').forEach((dir, index, splits) => {
        if (index !== splits.length - 1) {
            const parent = splits.slice(0, index).join('/');
            const dirPath = path.resolve(parent, dir);
            if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
            }
        }
    });
    fs.writeFileSync(targetDir, string);
    console.log(targetDir);
});
```

This code is from the blog: ["Angular v4 Universal Demystified"](https://medium.com/@feloy/angular-v4-universal-demystified-f06a576d6ca2)

Comment: what are you trying to do/achieve (too vague)

Comment: so you're building these pages... manually? - what does main.js do? - are you piping these arguments into angular-cli? i'm not entirely sure hwo your generate the final html files

Comment: yes, that's basically my question, how do I do that? I'm new to node.js. Thought about making an array with all the lines of code but I don't know how...

Comment: what does main js do? - are you generating the final html file based on the arguments?

Comment: yes, i can show it

Comment: p.s I didn't make it. It's from a startup with angular4 universal blog. I will put a link to it in the description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142452/discussion-between-denis-tsoi-and-sam-van-beastlo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways that I know off the top of my head, exclusively using node (you could alternatively use a bash, python script)

1. Editing the main.js
2. creating a separate script.js which uses childExec

I'll assume we can edit main.js first (and update with childExec version later).

Note: I've removed non-relevant section of the code to focus on looping through the array of filenames

run with

> node dist/main.js dist/index.html dynamic

**main js**

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
//if (args.length != 3) {
//    process.stdout.write("Usage: node dist/main.js <document> <distDir> <url>\n");
//    process.exit();
//}

var arr = ['page.html', 'page2.html'] //etc

arr.forEach(function(file) {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    document: indexFileContent,
    url: file // -> this is what we need to change page.html
  }).then(string => {
    let destUrl = file; // -> page.html
    if (destUrl == '/')
        destUrl = 'index.html'
    const targetDir = args[1] + '/' + destUrl;
    targetDir.split('/').forEach((dir, index, splits) => {
        if (index !== splits.length - 1) {
            const parent = splits.slice(0, index).join('/');
            const dirPath = path.resolve(parent, dir);
            if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
            }
        }
    });
    fs.writeFileSync(targetDir, string);
    console.log(targetDir);
  });
});
```

**Explaination:**

The script uses the format `node dist/main.js <document> <distDir> <url>` to render the files, as we are removing the `arg[2]/<url>` with the array of files in the declared `arr` array. This removes the need to manually type the required files.